# req.params.number is string in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

I am writing expressjs app. is req.params.anything always string and not number
suppose if I pass a number for user_id it's typeof is always string.

```
app.get('user/:user_id', function(req, res){
  console.log(typeof req.params.user_id);
});
```

GET user/21

this logs string.

So is it always type string for req.params.x?

Comment: You can define your own parameters, in that case they can be of any type. [Documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param).

Comment: Express simply parses url string with `RegExp`. So, if you need it to be a number you may convert it yourself: `req.params.x = parseInt(req.params.x)`.

Comment: Hint: `Number(req.params.x)` is faster than `parseInt(req.params.x)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, all params will be strings.

This is extracted from the expressjs `route.js`:

```
var val = 'string' == typeof m[i]
  ? decodeURIComponent(m[i])
  : m[i];
```

So the `val` will always be a string, since the result of `decodeURIComponent` is always a string, while `m` is the result of a RegExp.exec() which returns an array of matched strings, so it's also safe to assume that `m[i]` will be a string.

Comment: This is not a good answer. You should provide more information how you know they are always strings. Do you mind sharing your source on this?

Comment: The answer to your previous comment: from experience. Nice of you to edit your mean comment.

Comment: Your explanation is incorrect. `decodeURIComponent` will be called (and return a string) only if `m[i]` is a string. If `m[i]` is not a string, then `decodeURIComponent` is not called and `val` will not be a string.

Comment: `m` is an array of strings. Check out `RegExp.exec()`. So it's safe to assume that `m[i]` will be a string or `undefined`.